# How to tell zsh to directly enter the auto-completion list?

Tags: command-line, zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

When I am using zsh (default installation of oh-my-zsh) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it auto-completes the path which is very useful.

If there is only one candidate the auto-completion system just add the candidate to the path you're currently typing, as expected!

But if there are more than one candidate it displays a list below the PS for you to see, from here you have two choices:

1. You see one item in the list that matches your intention, you start
   typing the first letters and tab again to autocomplete the full
   word.
2. You tab directly after the list appears and then you can use the
   navigation keybindings to select an item in the list and then press
   enter to append the selected item in the current path you're typing.

In the second case you've pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> two times in a row, the second <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter the navigation mode.

Is there a way to tell `zsh` to directly enter the navigation list, in other words to highlight the first item if there is a list of choices?

Comment: Possibly just a matter of doing `set -o menucomplete`. See `info zsh menucomplete` for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas merci

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
zstyle ':completion:::::default' menu yes select
```

- A `zstyle` statement is kind of like a CSS rule, with the first argument functioning similar to a CSS selector (or namespace), the second argument being like a CSS property, and all further arguments being values. To override OMZ's [`zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:*' menu select`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/5403db85998ff0c087bc97d972e1e76551127b7e/lib/completion.zsh#L14), like in CSS, we need to either use a "heavier" selector or use the same selector but set it later (the latter of which completely replaces the existing rule). Here, I've made our selector heavier by adding `default` to it. We can omit the `*`s, because those parts of the selector are always empty for the `default` tag.
- When `select` is one of the values assigned to the `menu` attribute, it tells the completion systems to always use menu selection *when using menu completion.* With that last clause lies a problem in OMZ’s implementation: Even though OMZ's rule tells Zsh to always use selection when using the menu, it does *not* tell Zsh to always use the menu. To always start menu completion on the first try, we need to add `yes`.

---

Alternatively, if you get tired of trying to configure Zsh's completion system, try my [Zsh Autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty simple way to achieve this. I don't know oh-my-zsh, but I know this *issue*.
It's as simple as including `zstyle '*' single-ignored complete` somewhere in your shell config, preferably *after* your oh-my-zsh config gets loded.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried to include that in my `~/.zshrc` after the `oh-my-zsh` sourcing but it has no effect even I restart the shell. Any others ideas ? (thx btw)